# Problem with New Users

Tags: discussion

(I apologize in advance if this question should be asked in a more private setting). There are two new users who have names uncannily similar to my user name who appear to be "trolling" me. It is not just my paranoia, as my user name is rather unique. One of them has answered one of the questions I answered. Should I just leave this be, or is this something that requires action? (obviously, I've done nothing yet).

Comment: Please flag one of your questions or answers, giving details so that we can check.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : will do, thanks.

Comment: I must admit, that is a pretty weird (though legitimate) problem.

Comment: A cup of tea solves any problem/

Comment: I am under the impression such childish events occur only on math.stackexchange

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent : As opposed to...?

Comment: @Coffee_Table stats.stackexchange, stackoverflow, tex.stackexchange